# Find index number of div that matches result

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs with the same class, that contain links.

```
<select id="PSelect" name="Pselect">
    <option value="">Items</option>
    <option id="scarf" value="White Scarf">White Scarf</option>
    <option id="shirt" value="Black Shirt">Black Shirt</option>
    <option id="jacket" value="White Jacket">White Jacket</option>
    <option id="gloves" value="Yellow Gloves">Yellow Gloves</option>
</select>




<div><div class="PLink"><a href="product/scarf">Green Scarf</a></div></div>
<div><div class="PLink"><a href="product/shirt">Black Shirt</a></div></div>
<div><div class="PLink"><a href="product/jacket">White Jacket</a></div></div>
<div><div class="PLink"><a href="product/gloves">Yellow Gloves</a></div></div>
```

The select box contains the part of the string found in the URL's above. I want to be able to return the position of the div that matches the string in the select box. This sounds like an odd thing to do, but the resulting index number will eventually trigger another function.

For example, if someone selects "gloves" from the dropdown, I want the result to be "4" - as this is the index number of the div that contains the class "PLink" and contains the matching string in the URL. So far I have managed to isolate the part of the URL I need, but I just need to be able to return the index number of the div:

So far I have this:

```
$(".PLink a").each(function () {
    var href=$(this).prop('href');
    var n = href.lastIndexOf('/');
    var cat_code = href.substring(n + 1);
});
```

Comment: If you always, only, have `<div .PLink><a>...` then change your `.each` to `.each(function(i) {` and `i` => the index.   Note indices start at 0 so your example would be "3" not "4".

Comment: Would you mind giving some context on why you need the index? I can think of a handful of XY-problems that this might solve(ish), but very few good uses for it. If this is part of a bigger problem we may be able to suggest an entirely differnet approach.

Comment: Note that the `<div class='PLink'`>` "index" will always be 0/zero as you have each one wrapped in *another* div, so there's no siblings.   If you want it to be the index within all other PLinks, then you can do `$(".PLink").index($(this).closest(".PLink"))`  where `this` is the `a`

Answer (score 0):

Updated code as per your modified question

```js
$("#PSelect").on("change", function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var matchingIndex = $("#PSelect option[value='" + selectedValue + "']").index();

    console.log("matchingIndex " + matchingIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="PSelect" name="Pselect">
  <option value="">Items</option>
  <option id="scarf" value="Green Scarf">Green Scarf</option>
  <option id="shirt" value="Black Shirt">Black Shirt</option>
  <option id="jacket" value="White Jacket">White Jacket</option>
  <option id="gloves" value="Yellow Gloves">Yellow Gloves</option>
</select>

<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/scarf">Green Scarf</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/shirt">Black Shirt</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/jacket">White Jacket</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/gloves">Yellow Gloves</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added context and the select box to the original question now :)

Comment: @Gary Updated the code as per your modified question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result using attribute selector `[]` and `.index()` method from jquery. Check my comments in the code.

References

- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp
- https://api.jquery.com/index/

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  // get current selected value
  let val = $(this).val();

  if (val) {
    // selector ".PLink a[href$='" + val + "']" will try to find any a which is having href value ends with val.
    // we can use href*=val to check for contains & href^=val to check starts with
    // Then use .index and provide selector for actual list from which we need to get index of selected element.
    // index value will start from 0. So in your case you need to use index + 1
    let index = $(".PLink a[href$='" + val + "']").index('.PLink a');
    if (index != -1) {
      alert(index + 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/scarf">Green Scarf</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/shirt">Black Shirt</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/jacket">White Jacket</a></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="PLink"><a href="product/gloves">Yellow Gloves</a></div>
</div>

<select>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="scarf">scarf</option>
  <option value="shirt">shirt</option>
  <option value="jacket">jacket</option>
  <option value="gloves">gloves</option>
</select>
```